# Addition with ones and tens

Tags: logic, puzzle

The children on the planet Veeton count in Zips and Zaps.

If the sum is correct how many Zaps make a Zip?

\begin{array}{ccc}
 & \text{Zips} &  \text{Zaps} \\
 &      3      &       8 \\
+&      2      &       4 \\
\hline
 &      6      &       3
\end{array}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b$ is how many zaps make a zip, the addition is
$$
(3b+8)+(2b+4)=\dots
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer b as 9 with your method, but the answer is given as 3.

Comment: @DineshSunny That answer doesn't make sense, unless the digit have different meaning than usual. In that case the answer can be basically any number $\ge5$ (because there are at least five distinct digits).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

They're telling you that 12 zaps and 5 zips is the same as 3 zaps and 6 zips.

Comment: Thank you Nick, got that hint. Can you please explain in detail?